# Binding in code does not work when the control derives from another control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am creating some custom control, and I found myself in a situation where anything I try fails, I’ve got everything working apart from two things.
I created a small demo app just to demonstrate the issue:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"       
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
  <StackPanel>
     <TextBox x:Name="MyName" Text="{Binding MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
     <local:MyContentControl />
   </StackPanel>
 </Window>

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
     }
 }

 public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
     private string myProperty;
     public string MyProperty
     {
         get { return myProperty; }
         set
         {
             myProperty = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
 }

 public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
 {
     public MyContentControl()
     {
         Loaded += MyTextBlock_Loaded;
     }

     private void MyTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         var textbox = new TextBox();
         textbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, "MyProperty");
         textbox.TextChanged += Textbox_TextChanged;
     }

     private void Textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
 }
```

So inside MyContentControl this TextChanged event is never fired, however the code gets to the loaded event, and there is no output error complaining about the binding. I am not quite sure why.

Does anybody know what am I missing here?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your MyContentControl code like this:

```
public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyContentControl()
    {
        Loaded += MyTextBlock_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = new TextBox();            
        textbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("MyProperty"));
        textbox.TextChanged += Textbox_TextChanged;
        // note this line
        this.Content = textbox;
    }

    private void Textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You will understand the reason. In Loaded event you create new TextBox(), but you don't put it anywhere in UI. So it's kind of "orphaned" control with no parent. If there is no parent, there is no DataContext, and bindings cannot work.

Comment: I see, it makes sense now :) thank you. It allowed me to finish complicated control. Which uses textblock to display data, but I was not able to have textchanged event for textblock. Thats why I wanted to add textbox and use its event. So it is part of the content now, but its visibility is hidden, and any time the bound text changes I can update my textblock :)